# I would like to create a Confluence child wiki page under a parent page thru a python/java script

Tags: javascript, python, confluence

I am able to create a page under a space by a below mentioned script but i want yo add this same page under some folder 
e.g. like this page is created under a folder
Hand-Off Document
however i want to create a page under a folder
Hand-Off Document /Handoff Document Home / QAgent  Signature Set: Windows
how can i generate page under this hierarchy by a script

```
import xmlrpclib
CONFLUENCE_URL = "https://qwiki.intranet.qualys.com/rpc/xmlrpc"
CONFLUENCE_LOGIN = "XXX"
CONFLUENCE_PASSWORD = "XXx"

client = xmlrpclib.Server(CONFLUENCE_URL, verbose = 0)
auth_token = client.confluence2.login(CONFLUENCE_LOGIN, CONFLUENCE_PASSWORD)

newpagedata = {"title":"TEST_page_sha","content":"new content","space":"XXX"}
newpage = client.confluence1.storePage(auth_token, newpagedata);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `XML/RPC` is deprecated in Confluence since Confluence 5.5 and they replaced it with `REST API`. If you don't have any restriction and you are flexible to use `REST API` instead of old `XML/RPC` you can create child page by specifying your parent page with `ancestors` .

Technically, in order to create a Page in Confluence via REST API you can use following:

```
curl -v -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","title":"Parent Page","space":{"key":"ATTACH"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic"
```

For creating child page you can use following:

```
curl -v -u admin:admin -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d'{"type":"page","ancestors":[{"type":"page","id":1048582}]‌​,"title":"Child Page","space":{"key":"ATTACH"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"<‌​p>This is a new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}}' "http://localhost:8090/rest/api/content/?os_authType=basic"
```

Comment: If It helped you please feel free to mark it as answer so it will help other people as well :-)